# Rebuild mount points after destroying partitions

Tags: mount, partition

When I installed Ubuntu, I had a partitions with the windows OS installed, but now I've made some changes, I've erased Windows, created two new partitions in the storage ocuppied by windows before, and installed Linux Mint and a new /home partition for Linux Mint.

But now, when I go to my Ubuntu, the system does obviously try to mount the disappeared partition in the `windows` folder.

How can I change the default booting mount points?

PD: I understand that isn't a Ubuntu specific question, since the same problem would be appear in the same situation with other Linux-base OS.

Answer (score 3):

On any *nix system, `/etc/fstab` file contains the list of mountable file-system. Something like:

```
/dev/sda2     swap                 swap       defaults              0 0
/dev/sdc1     /                    ext4       acl,user_xattr        1 1
/dev/sda1     /boot                ext4       acl,user_xattr        1 2
/dev/sdb1     /home                reiserfs   acl,user_xattr        1 2
proc          /proc                proc       defaults              0 0
sysfs         /sys                 sysfs      noauto                0 0
debugfs       /sys/kernel/debug    debugfs    noauto                0 0
/dev/sda3     /mnt/windows         vfat       default               0 0
```

Probably, you need only find the right line, like the the last one in the example, and delete them.

**WARNING**: any error in this file could make you system unusable or worse. Please, execute the command `man fstab` and read carefully it before editing the file.